# How to rotate a group of text elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/j0gnm5mw/1/

I have a group of text elements i create like so :

```
var text = container.append('g').selectAll('text');

text.data(testData).enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('x', function(d, i) {
    return (i + 1) * 100;
  })
  .attr('y', 100)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.label;
  })
```

I try to rotate like so :

```
.attr("transform", "rotate(-10)");
```

I have found a few examples similar to this :

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4403522

They do the following to rotate :

```
.selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(90)")
    .style("text-anchor", "start");
```

However this still gives the same output.

Comment: I think I have to translate and then rotate, ill give that a go and see where I get

Comment: You can rotate about a different centre via rotate(angle, x, y)

Comment: This statement is not true _But this rotates the group of text elements not each one individually._ if you inspect the text DOM element you will see the rotate `rotate(-10)` in each text element, this is not applied to the group.

Comment: @RobertLongson great, it works, and Cyril, my mistake, at first glance it does look like it only applies to the group, I shall edit

Comment: Cyril is right, `rotate` is applied to each element individually. The problem is that they rotate around the origin, and that's why it seems to be a "group behaviour". See this: *If optional parameters x and y are not supplied, the rotate is about the origin of the current user coordinate system*.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Robert Longson, it has been solved.

I didn't realise you can rotate about a different centre point. So now my rotate function looks like so :

```
  var thisX = (i + 1) * 100, thisY = 100 ;
  return "rotate(-90," + thisX + ","+ thisY+")";
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/j0gnm5mw/4/